# PHP5.5 right path for the /sources.list

Tags: php-5.5, debian-based

I can't find the right path of PHP5.5 for the /sources.list, any advice?

```
xxxxxx@xxxx:/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.5.7# apt-get build-dep 5.5*                                                                                                                
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                            
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list                                                                                                                                  
xxxxxx@xxxx:/usr/local/src/php5-build/php-5.5.7#
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like the build not applied in the set of Debian9 and php5.5, 5.4. The installation was completed by ./configure

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libfcgi-dev libfcgi0ldbl libjpeg62-dbg libmcrypt-dev libssl-dev
mkdir /opt/php-5.4.45
mkdir /usr/local/src/php5
wget http://de2.php.net/get/php 5.4.45.tar.gz/from/this/mirror -O php-5.4.45.tar.gz
tar -xzvf php-5.4.45.tar.gz
cd php-5.4.45
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.4.45 --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --enable-mbstring --enable-sockets --enable-exif --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-zip --enable-ftp --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir --with-bz2 --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-pcre-regex --with-libxml-dir=/usr --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --with-mysql
make
make install
```